# Is there a way to copy/paste action-keyframes with python script in Blender?

Tags: python, blender

I have a lot of blend files and also a lot of animations(actions) on each one.
I need to move all the keyframes for all the actions by 15 frames and i can do it with (for many files with the help powershell):

```py
    for action in bpy.data.actions: 
        for fcurve in action.fcurves:
            for point in fcurve.keyframe_points:
                point.co.x += 15.0
```

before the script
[image]

after the script
[image]

And this actually works, the problem is that i need to export them as fbx, 
so when exporting animations it ignore the first 14 frames because they are empty. What i need is to copy/paste or duplicate the frame # 15 in to frame # 0, to get an static animation at the beginning (i will use it to fade between animation).

And this is the result that i want:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [insert a new keyframe point](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FCurveKeyframePoints.html) with the frame as 1 and the value from the first keyframe.

```
for action in bpy.data.actions:
    for fcurve in action.fcurves:
        fcurve.keyframe_points.insert(1, fcurve.keyframe_points[0].co.y)
```

If you want to copy or set other properties, the insert returns the new [keyframe](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Keyframe.html).

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for. Now I see that it was not necessarily copy and paste the frames. I just needed the first 15 frames to be static, to improve certain transitions in other software. I really appreciate the answer, I had been looking for a while. Also, I will read the reference for "keyframes" to see what else I can do.

Comment: @JavierSantos you can find some more fancy keyframing [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/111644/935).